# Borel action and stabilizer map

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory

Let $G$ be a countable discrete group and endow the set of subgroups, Sub$(G)$ with the Chabauty topology - this, when $G$ is discrete, is just the subspace-product topology inherited from $2^G$. $G$ can be given a metric (see article)

Suppose that $X$ is a probability space (isomorphic to a compact metric space, with a regular-Borel probability measure) and that $G$ acts on $X$. Assume further that this action is Borel.

Define $f:X \to $ Sub$(G)$ by $x \mapsto \text{Stab}_G(x)$. Why is this function Borel?

I've tried:

Take a basic open set in Sub$(G)$, of the form $\{H \leq G : g_i \in G\}:=U$ for some $g_i \in G$.

Then $f^{-1}(U) = \{x \in X : x.g_i = x\} = \text{Fix}(g_i)$.

However I'm not sure why this set may be Borel, and specifically how to use the fact that the action is Borel. What do you think?

See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.08381.pdf for all the precise details. The question comes up on page 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $g\in G$. Consider the map $\phi: X\to X\times X$ given by $x\mapsto (x,g\cdot x)$. This is Borel. Let $\Delta\subset X\times X$ be the diagonal, i.e. $\Delta:=\{(x,x):x\in X\}$. Then $\Delta$ is Borel (in fact closed). Then
$$
\phi^{-1}(\Delta)=\{x\in X: (x,g\cdot x)\in \Delta)\} =\{x\in X: g\cdot x=x\}
$$
But the LHS is Borel.

Comment: indeed! thanks you